# handling null pointer exception in talend in OR statement

Tags: java, talend

I have this code.  it is the row exception filter in the right hand map of a `tMap`:

```
row2.method.equals("Twitter") && (
    row2.last_notified.equals(null) ||
    row2.frequency.equals("Everytime") || 
    (row2.frequency == "Hourly" && TalendDate.diffDate(TalendDate.addDate(row2.last_notified,1,"HH"), TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", TalendDate.getDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")), "HH") > 0) ||
    (row2.frequency == "Daily" && TalendDate.diffDate(TalendDate.addDate(row2.last_notified,1,"dd"), TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", TalendDate.getDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")), "dd") > 0)
)
```

I have a nullPointerException.  I know that `frequency` is not null, as is `method`.  I know that `last_notified` is null.  based on my logic, all rows with `"Twitter"` as a value with no `last_notified` should pass.  However, it looks like I failed with this.

I understood that OR statements go from left to right.  If the first value comes back `True`, then the OR SHOULD return true?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding

```
row2.last_notified.equals(null)
```

Don't test for null with the `equals` method as that risks throwing the NPE exception since you'll be attempting to call a method on a null variable.  Always use `==` instead since you're not testing the notified reference's value but rather whether the reference itself is null.

So do

```
row2.last_notified == null
```

Also regarding

```
row2.frequency == "Daily"
```

It's the exact opposite here as you're comparing Strings wrong -- use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Instead do:

```
row2.frequency.equals("Daily")
```

Comment: This is awesome!  thank you so much.  I will accept, when the timer allows me.